# I'm having a hard time using pass by reference

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I don't know why I keep on getting errors in my code when I'm trying to do pass-by-reference, for finding the largest number of an integer using recursion.

My code works when it's pass-by-value, but I fail to do it correctly in pass-by-reference.

---

My main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void largest_digit(int* digit);

int main() {
   int num;

   printf("\nPlease enter a number ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   largest_digit(&num);
   printf("The largest digit = %d\n", num);

   return 0;
}
```

---

My function:

```
void largest_digit(int* digit) {
   int hold, hold1;

    if(*digit == 0 || *digit < 0) {
        *digit = 0;
        *digit;
        return;
    }

    // If-statement with Recursion.
    if(*digit > 0){
        hold = *digit % 10;
        hold1 = largest_digit(*digit/10);

        if(hold > hold1) {
            hold = *digit;
            *digit;
            return;
        } else {
            hold1 = *digit;
            *digit;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please properly indent and space your code in a readable manner...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to StackOverflow but, isn't my code in a readable manner?

Comment: It's hard to read in its current state.

Comment: @marcoBonelli I just fixed it so it's easier to read the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code only assigns to `*digit` in the terminal case for recursion, and only assigns zero in that case. I'm guessing some of those lines that assign `hold = *digit;` (which is never used again, same for `hold1`) and just plain `*digit;` (??? That does nothing useful) are supposed to assign to `*digit`?

Comment: Replace the recursion with a loop and it will work as you intend.

Comment: `largest_digit(*digit/10);` should give a compilation error. If you don't see an error message then adjust your compiler settings as the current settings are causing you to waste time by not highlighting the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone said before, the `largest_digit` function is void, so it can't be assinged to a variable when is called. What you can do instead, is modifying `*digit` before the call, and then assign the value of `*digit` to what you want, in this case `hold1`.

Other thing is that you need to save the value into `*digit` before returning, for example, instead of doing `hold = *digit`, you should do `*digit = hold`.

Here are the suggested modifications:

```c
void largest_digit(int* digit) {
   int hold, hold1;

    if(*digit == 0 || *digit < 0) {
        *digit = 0;
        return;
    }

    // If-statement with Recursion.
    if(*digit > 0){
        hold = (*digit) % 10;
        (*digit) /= 10;
        largest_digit(digit);
        hold1 = *digit;

        if(hold > hold1) {
            *digit = hold;
            return;
        } else {
            *digit = hold1;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

With this main,

```c
int main() {

   int a=123, b=652, c=3274;
   largest_digit(&a);
   largest_digit(&b);
   largest_digit(&c);
   printf("%d\n",a);
   printf("%d\n",b);
   printf("%d\n",c);

   return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
3
6
7
```

Comment: I fixed my code to what you had, and it works. I guess I screwed up with using the pointers when trying to do recursion.

Comment: @learning good to hear that it serves you, but what is important is that you understand how it does. If you have any doubts about the code tell me

Answer (score 1):

You said you were passing it by reference, but you just tried to pass it by value here

`hold1 = largest_digit(*digit/10);`

Create a new int with *digit/10 and pass the address to largest_digit

```
int hold1Temp = *digit/10;
hold1 = largest_digit(&hold1Temp);
```

EDIT: Your function should be something like this:

```
void largest_digit (int* digit)
{
  if (*digit <= 0) return; // if there's no more digit to compare, stop
  int currentDigit = *digit % 10; // if you receive 982, it gets the 2
  int nextDigit = *digit/10; // if you receive 982, it turns into 98
  largest_digit(&nextDigit); // does the same thing again
  *digit = currentDigit > nextDigit ? currentDigit : nextDigit; // chooses the biggest digit
}
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'll try that new way.

Comment: Digit is the pointer. When you do *digit you just got the value inside it, and tried to pass it as the pointer. It will probably try to dereference this value (assuming it is a pointer) and crash in the second iteration.

Comment: @Gabriel, `largest_digit` is a `void` function so assigning the result to a variable isn't quite right.

Comment: @idz true that. Just wanted to show the issue with the pointer, didn't even look at the return value of the function.

Comment: I did your changes, and my errors are down, but I have one more error with **hold = *digit % 10:**

Comment: Question: What exactly did you want to accomplish with your code? I could provide you a way shorter and clearer alternative. :)

So far, I think you wanted 
```
void largest_digit (int* digit)
{

}
```

Comment: @Gabriel My goal was to find the largest digit using recursion and to use the function with pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things first:

1. The unary indirection operator (`*`) used on a pointer means "look at what is this pointing to". Therefore, the statement `*digit;` alone is not useful to anything. You can very well remove it from your code (I see you use it multiple times), perhaps you meant to do an assignment? The statement `*digit = X;` is an assignment and modifies the data pointed by the pointer.
2. "Passing by reference" does not exist in C. You can only pass by value. That value though can be a pointer to another value, that is how you "simulate" passing something by reference.
3. A function declared as `void f(...)` does not return any value. Therefore, assigning the "return value" of such a function to a variable does not make sense.

---

Now, considered the above:

Your call `largest_digit(*digit/10)` is not passing a pointer, but dereferencing the pointer `digit`, dividing the value by 10, and then passing that as parameter. As you already figured, this is wrong. To correctly pass by reference in your case, you would need to either modify the original value pointed to by `digit`, or create a new one and pass its address.

In any case, passing a pointer around (instead of the value directly) for this kind of recursive function does not make much sense and is only a complicated twist that does not accomplish much other than making your life harder. Use a plain value as argument.

```c
int largest_digit(int num) {
    if (num < 0)
        return largest_digit(-num);

    if (num == 0)
        return 0;

    int cur = num % 10;
    int next = largest_digit(num / 10);

    if (cur > next)
        return cur;

    return next;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", largest_digit(1923)); // 9
    printf("%d\n", largest_digit(4478)); // 8
    printf("%d\n", largest_digit(-123)); // 3
}
```

NOTE: for simplicity, the above function also handles negative numbers by calling `largest_digit(-num)` if the number is negative, therefore it only supports negative digits **down to `INT_MIN+1`** (that is, it does not correctly handle `INT_MIN`).

Comment: If pass by reference does not exist in C, how can there be a dereference operator? Pointers are references, passing a pointer is in fact passing a reference, and the C standard uses this terminology. This is what was called pass by reference before C++ existed. C++ introduced a new feature and called it a reference, and people started using terminology differently in respect to C++. But it has not changed for C. In C, passing a pointer is pass by reference.

Comment: @EricPostpischil AFAIK, at least for C99, there is no definition of "reference", nor mention of "passing by reference" anywhere in the standard. The only case in which the word is used it has its "plain" English meaning. The closest you can find is §6.2.5.20 paragraph 5: *"A pointer  type  describes  an  object  whose  value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type"*. The `*` operator is never called "dereference operator" (I shall correct my phrasing in the first point above).

Comment: The standard says a pointer provides a reference. Pointers get passed. That is pass by reference. That is how the terminology was used before C++ existed, and it is how the terminology is still used.

Comment: C 2018 index: “dereference, see indirection operator”. Also refers to dereferencing in a note. And this is not in dispute; a pointer is a reference, so getting the object from the reference is dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is that other than the case where `*digit` is negative, you never actually set `*digit`. Each time you do this:

```
*digit;
```

The above only dereferences the pointer and looks up the value, but it doesn't actually *change* it. What you need to do on each of your return routes is to actually *set* the value to something:

```
*digit = ...something...;
```

Without setting this value anywhere, the value of `num` in your `main()` function is never actually going to change.

In addition, you are treating `largest_digit` as if it has a return value, which it does not:

```
hold1 = largest_digit(*digit/10); // <- assigning the return value does not make sense
```